# Pass var to jquery from div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a jquery function to open a dialog box, and I need to be able to change the height and the width of the box. I am wanting to pass it a parameter from within the DIV. I have looked at many different possibilities, but to no avail. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
$.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 500,
        show: "drop",
        hide: "drop"
    });
    $("#opener").click(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is my Div.

```
<div id="dialog">
   Some text here
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question/problem is.

Comment: DIVs are HTML elements - they are not concerned with variables. Please edit the question to be clear about what you're trying to do.

Comment: You mean you want to be able to resize the dialog box depending on parameters set in the div belonging the dialog?

Comment: Yes.  I found that I can supposedly pass a parameter back to the function from within a div something like this: <div id="dialog" class"default {'height': '300', 'width': '500'}"> and the height and width of the function would be like height=data.height; width=data.width

Comment: @user1518202 I updated my answer based on your comments. Is that close to what you're looking for?

Comment: @user1518202 Thanks for marking my answer as the accepted answer. Would it be too much trouble to ask for an upvote as well? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-width) you can make the window resizable, set a min/max height and width and set the height and width as options when calling the `.dialog()` method.

**From the documentation:**

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ width: 460 });
```

Get or set the width option, after init.

```
//getter
var width = $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "width" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "width", 460 );
```

It should be pretty simple to get whatever data or parameters you have stored in your div and pass it as an option to the `.dialog()` method.

**Update:**

From your comments, you want something like this:

**[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehzdB/)**

```
<div id="dialog" data-height="400" data-width="400" style="background-color: red;">
   Some text here
</div>
<a id="opener" href="#">Open dialog</a>​

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#opener").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dialogHeight = $("#dialog").data("height"),
            dialogWidth = $("#dialog").data("width");
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            height: dialogHeight,
            width: dialogWidth            
        });
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

We're adding this type of syntax to our jQuery setup files. This allows devs to easily implement things like this w/o having to write a lot of JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/iknowkungfoo/C4Zz6/20/

**HTML**

```
<div id="foo" class="dialog" data-width="100">Hello</div>
<a id="trigger" href="#">Open</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $_foo = $( "#foo" ), dW = 200, dH = 200

    $_foo.dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: dH,
        width: dW
    });

    $('#trigger').on("click", function(e){

        var params = { 
            height: ($_foo.data("height") ? $_foo.data("height") : dH),
            width: ($_foo.data("width") ? $_foo.data("width") : dW)
        }

        $_foo.dialog(params).dialog("open");

        e.preventDefault();

    });

});  ​
```